# How does the opaque property work in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, opacity

This a simple application I got from here [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545240/3769877)  to [How to set a Transparent Background of JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2545214/418556)
 that's supposed to explain how `setOpaque()` works.

```
public class TwoPanels {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    // setting layout to null so we can make panels overlap
    p.setLayout(null);

    CirclePanel topPanel = new CirclePanel();
    // drawing should be in blue
    topPanel.setForeground(Color.blue);
    // background should be black, except it's not opaque, so 
    // background will not be drawn
    topPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    // set opaque to false - background not drawn
    topPanel.setOpaque(false);
    topPanel.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
    // add topPanel - components paint in order added, 
    // so add topPanel first
     p.add(topPanel);

    CirclePanel bottomPanel = new CirclePanel();
    // drawing in green
    bottomPanel.setForeground(Color.green);
    // background in cyan
    bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    // and it will show this time, because opaque is true
    bottomPanel.setOpaque(true);
    bottomPanel.setBounds(30, 30, 100, 100);
    // add bottomPanel last...
    p.add(bottomPanel);

    // frame handling code...
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Two Panels");
    f.setContentPane(p);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

// Panel with a circle drawn on it.
private static class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

    // This is Swing, so override paint*Component* - not paint
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // call super.paintComponent to get default Swing 
        // painting behavior (opaque honored, etc.)
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        int width = getWidth() - 20;
        int height = getHeight() - 20;
        g.fillArc(x, y, width, height, 0, 360);
    }
}
}
```

The thing the I don't get is how come he is adding the opaque layer on top of transparent layer? shouldn't be the other way around?

The way that I picture how it should work is by adding the transparent layer on top of the opaque one, kinda of like how you put a screen protector over a phone(sorry for the dumb example)

Can someone please explain how transparency works in java?

I apologize of my question is a bit naive but this has been bothering me for a while!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPanel said to be opaque what does that mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416454/jpanel-said-to-be-opaque-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: Do you know about "alpha"?

Comment: I know what does the alpha value mean. but what does that have to do with my questions?

Comment: so alpha can be used to control the opacity of any components in java

Comment: Ok. I think a better questions could be in what order will the panels be painted? I put a print statement in each panel's paintComponent method and to my surprise the panel added later (the bottom panel) had it's paintComponent method called first. can you explain this please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the example reliest on the fact that with a `null` layout, the child components are indeed drawn in reverse order. An implementation dependency. That at least deserves mention. Adding a visible border would make it more evident:

```
private static class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    CirclePanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    }
```

Comment: even when I set a layout manager the `paintComponent` methods are still called in reverse order.

Comment: The layouts are positioned on _validation_ (invalidate/validate), a method `paintChildren` is called, and that of course uses the same code.