# Java - Attempting to draw multiple shapes at once, some are missing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jinternalframe

I am attempting to draw multiple shapes in the contentPane of a JInternalFrame. When a button is clicked, the program should determine which checkboxes are selected, and add the appropriate shapes.  If multiple shapes are selected, it should add all of them.

Currently the program can draw any of the shapes.  The problem is that on click, only one shape is being drawn when I have multiple check boxes selected, and I can't figure out why. (Example: Yellow and blue JCheckboxes are selected, it only draws the yellow shape, when it should draw both)  Please help me get the program to draw more than one shape on click!

Here is some code:

ActionListener that is to handle the adding of shapes:

```
class addListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (redBox.isSelected())
        {
            x = createRNG(RNG_MAX,RNG_MIN);//so the shapes starting location is random
            y = createRNG(RNG_MAX,RNG_MIN);
            rShape = new redShape(x,y);
            contentPane.add(rShape);//,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        if (blueBox.isSelected())
        {
            x = createRNG(RNG_MAX,RNG_MIN);
            y = createRNG(RNG_MAX,RNG_MIN);
            bShape = new bShape(x,y);
            //internalFrame.getContentPane().add(bShape);
            contentPane.add(bShape);//BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        if (yellowBox.isSelected())
        {
            x = createRNG(RNG_MAX,RNG_MIN);
            y = createRNG(RNG_MAX,RNG_MIN);
            yShape = new yShape(x,y);
            //internalFrame.getContentPane().add(yShape);
            contentPane.add(yShape);//,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }
        internalFrame.repaint();
        internalFrame.revalidate();
    }
}
```

The code of one of the shape classes.  The code of these classes are all basically the same, just different shapes being drawn.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class redShape extends coloredShapes
{
private static final int RECTANGLE_WIDTH = 80;
private static final int RECTANGLE_HEIGHT = 20;

private int xLeft;
private int yTop;

public redShape(int x, int y)
{
    xLeft = x;
    yTop = y;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //draws 1 large rectangle
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(xLeft,yTop,RECTANGLE_WIDTH,RECTANGLE_HEIGHT);

    //Divides the rectangle into parts
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(xLeft, yTop,xLeft+80,yTop);
    g.drawLine(xLeft,yTop,xLeft,yTop+20);
    g.drawLine(xLeft,yTop+20,xLeft+80,yTop+20);
    g.drawLine(xLeft+80,yTop+20,xLeft+80,yTop);
    g.drawLine(xLeft+20,yTop,xLeft+20,yTop+20);
    g.drawLine(xLeft+40,yTop,xLeft+40,yTop+20);
    g.drawLine(xLeft+60,yTop,xLeft+60,yTop+20);
}

public void moveComponentBy(int dx, int dy)
{
    if (yTop < 450)
    {
        xLeft += dx;
        yTop += dy;
        if (xLeft < 0)
        {
            xLeft = 0;
        }
        if (xLeft > 500)
        {
            xLeft = 500;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}

public int getYTop()
{
    return yTop;
}

public int getXLeft()
{
    return xLeft;
}
}
```

This is the code I thought would be relevant,  if any further code is needed to determine the issue, please ask and I will provide it!

EDIT: 
coloredShapes abstract class, as requested.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
abstract public class coloredShapes extends JComponent
{     
private static final int RECTANGLE_WIDTH = 10;
private static final int RECTANGLE_HEIGHT = 10;

private int xLeft;
private int yTop;

public coloredShapes()
{
    xLeft = 0;
    yTop = 0;
}

public abstract void moveComponentBy(int dx, int dy);

public abstract int getYTop();

public abstract int getXLeft();
}
```

Comment: If  the shape classes are the same, the problem is most likly in the booleanvalues (the `#Selected()` calls). If you are not sure what is happening, maybe its worth debugging your code and see where things go wrong.

Comment: When paintComponent the 0,0 will be the position from whitin the current JComponent, with your logic, you may create a custom JInternalFrame that accepts the shapes and draw then on position

Comment: @Justiciar Can you show your ColoredShapes class? Is it a component? Where is your paintComponent method for your main panel?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) If my guesses are correct, the code not shown is using a `JComponent` as the parent of the `coloredShapes` class, and this is likely not the best way to create more than one colored shape. ..

Comment: .. Better to use a single custom painted component that has a list of shapes to be drawn, then in the paint method, iterate the list and paint each in turn.

Comment: @user3437460  coloredShapes is actually just an abstract class that does nothing by itself.  I've posted it's code as an edit in the original post

Comment: @Justiciar And so, ColoredShapes indeed extends to JComponent. Unfortunately, this is not how you should do custom paintings. If you were to draw a JComponent freely on anywhere on the screen, you need to set the layout to null. But the best way is not to do that, but keep a list of Shapes and draw the shapes directly on the panel.

Comment: @user3437460 I am not very experienced with custom painting.  Might you have a link to a tutorial that goes over what you are recommending?

edit: thanks camickr .  I'm looking over that now

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do incremental painting. The example uses a "ColoredRectangle" to draw rectangles. You can easily change this class to hold a `Polygon` and then just paint the Polygon using the drawShape(...) method of the Graphics2D class.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use `Borderlayout` for your `JInternalFrame`.
From what I see I assume you add all shapes to the JInternalFrame by: `contentPane.add(bShape);` which adds `bShape` to  `Borderlayout` center.

`Borderlayout` center can hold one component. Adding a second one overwrites the first. 
For testing you can `setLayout(null);` to the `JInternalFrame` (and set bounds of the components added). For a more robust solution see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675914/how-to-put-a-component-on-top-of-others).

Also make sure that the background you paint is transparent. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545214/how-to-set-a-transparent-background-of-jpanel) for more details.

Comment: The JInternalFrame is actually using the default layout, which I assume to be flow.  I did set the contentPane to borderLayout however.  I am looking into StackLayout now, I actually hadn't heard of that before.

Comment: Layout shouldn't affect custom paintings. If your shape is not a component and you are just drawing it, it should not be affected. It is more likely how you draw the shapes in paintComponent.

Comment: It may have nothing to do with the painting but with the attempt to add multiple components.

Comment: @Justiciar Actually, the default layout for all windows is `BorderLayout`, including `JInternalFrame`

Comment: @c0der I'm having trouble trying to implement the StackLayout you mentioned.  Are you sure StackLayout can be used in Swing?  From what I can see it is for SWT, which I am not using(and have never used before)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Got confused with JavaFx. I'll amend my answer